# How to use action/method in other HTML elements (not form)

Tags: html, list, forms, post

Is it possible to use the attributes `action` and `method` in other HTML elements rather than `<form>`?

The idea is that when the user clicks `Account Settings` from list `Settings` (in home page):

1. I want to load some data from the database using NODE
2. Modify `accountSettings.html`
3. Then load the page

Here is some HTML code (will give `Cannot GET /goToSettings` error on browser):

```
<li class="navigation__sub">
    <a href="#"> Settings</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/goToSettings" method="POST"> Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Privacy & Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Notifications & Sounds</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> User Preferences</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Report a problem</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

app.js

```
router.post('/goToSettings', (req, res) => {
    console.log("PERFORMING CHANGES BEFORE PAGE LOAD");

    return res.redirect('/accountSettings.html');
});
```

I have tried surrounding it with `<form>` but this will kick the element out of the list, and also doesn't work:

```
<form action="/goToSettings" method="POST">
      <li><a> Account Settings</a></li>
</form>
```

---

### SOLUTION:

`<li><a href="/goToSettings"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Account Settings</a></li>`

```
router.get('/goToSettings', (req, res) => {
    console.log("PERFORMING CHANGES BEFORE PAGE LOAD");

    return res.redirect('/accountSettings.html');
});
```

Comment: Using a POST request to *get* the account settings page doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Quentin. I marked your comment as useful as it helped me solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

The `action` and `method` attribute can only function when being used with a form element. Instead, you could try using an ajax request with a `FormData` object. It will also not require you to reload the page.

```
//creates HTTP request and form data object
const xhhtp=new XMLHttpRequest, formData=new FormData();

xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if(this.status===200&&this.readyState===4){
    //function to load data based on response
    loadData(this.responseText);
  }
}

//appends key value pair to formdata
formData.append("KEY","VALUE");

xhttp.open("POST","https://URL",true);

//sends ajax request using formdata
xhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: Will try this out. Is this NODE or pure JS?

Comment: client side javascript

Comment: maybe in the future i will use this but for now I have found a solution. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I think the `method` and `action` attributes are available for `<form>` elements only